# Textboxes being treated as <td> elements by css are not aligning with corresponding text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create three textboxes in a row, but the text that should be adjacent (to the left) to the text boxes is being pushed down so that it is to the left (but below) the text boxes. I've included the html and css.

```css
fieldset {
  display: block;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*margin-left: 2px;*/
  /*margin-right: 2px;*/
  padding-top: 0.35em;
  padding-bottom: 0.625em;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  border: 2px groove;
}


/*the .table class id was originally provided by stackoverflow, however, when using it on the fieldset
    it causes everything to be aligned to the left.
    */

.table {
  display: table;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}

.td.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Scars, Marks, Tattoos (Describe):</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea name="susScarsEtc" rows="5" cols="20">Nothing notable.</textarea></div>
    <div class="td right">General Appearance (Describe):</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea name="susGenAppear" rows="5" cols="20">Nothing notable.</textarea></div>
    <div class="td right">Distinguishing Handicap(s) (Describe):</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea name="susHandicap" rows="5" cols="20">Nothing notable.</textarea></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: There's no `class="table"` in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `td` styles (and add `class="table"` to your `fieldset`).

```css
fieldset {
  display: block;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*margin-left: 2px;*/
  /*margin-right: 2px;*/
  padding-top: 0.35em;
  padding-bottom: 0.625em;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  border: 2px groove;
}


/*the .table class id was originally provided by stackoverflow, however, when using it on the fieldset
    it causes everything to be aligned to the left.
    */

.table {
  display: table;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.td.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Scars, Marks, Tattoos (Describe):</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea name="susScarsEtc" rows="5" cols="20">Nothing notable.</textarea></div>
    <div class="td right">General Appearance (Describe):</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea name="susGenAppear" rows="5" cols="20">Nothing notable.</textarea></div>
    <div class="td right">Distinguishing Handicap(s) (Describe):</div>
    <div class="td"><textarea name="susHandicap" rows="5" cols="20">Nothing notable.</textarea></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you tell me  how to add padding to the top and bottom of my table rows/td elements?

Comment: I've experimented with the padding-top/padding-bottom to no avail.

Comment: @StackBoy you can use border-spacing

Comment: Okay so I've added border spacing to my css and i doesn't appear to have changed the way things are displayed. (e.g:

.td {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-spacing: 10px 10px;
}. It appears that border-spacing attribute is only applicable to table elements.

Comment: @StackBoy so to the `.table` class from which it has to be applied

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, however, my .table class is causing everything to be aligned to the left.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved the problem you originally asked, and then ask a new question if you're having a different problem.