# border-spacing for fieldset elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to "pad" the elements of my fieldset and it was suggested that I used border spacing. Looking at w3 schools, it appears that border spacing is only for table elements, so I'm not sure what else to do. Here is my css and html. Using border-spacing made no changes to the display of the page.

```
fieldset {
    display: block;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    /*text-align: center;*/
    /*margin-left: 2px;*/
    /*margin-right: 2px;*/
    padding-top: 0.35em;
    padding-bottom: 0.625em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
    border: 2px groove;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/

}

.tr {
    display: table-row;
    /*padding-top: 0.35em;*/
    /*padding-bottom: 0.625em;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}

.td {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    /*border-spacing: 10px 50px;*/
}

.td.right {
    text-align: right;
}
<fieldset>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
                <div class="td"><input class="datepicker2" name="callDate"></div>
                <div class="td right">Caller code Number:</div>
                <div class="td"><input class="CodeMaker" name="callerCodeNum"></div>
                <div class="td right">Is there a warrant? If so what is the jurisdiction?</div>
                <div class="td"><input type="text" name="jurisdiction"></div>
            </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: How's this question different from [your last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204220/textboxes-being-treated-as-td-elements-by-css-are-not-aligning-with-correspond)?

Comment: It is the same question, I just didn't see that G-Cyr had posted the answer. :-/

How do I set up to have notifications emailed when someone has posted on a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `padding` on the `fieldset`:

```css
fieldset {
  display: block;
  border: 2px groove;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  /*padding-top: 0.35em;*/
  /*padding-bottom: 0.625em;*/
  vertical-align: top;
  border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*border-spacing: 10px 50px;*/
}

.td.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="datepicker2" name="callDate"></div>
    <div class="td right">Caller code Number:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="CodeMaker" name="callerCodeNum"></div>
    <div class="td right">Is there a warrant? If so what is the jurisdiction?</div>
    <div class="td"><input type="text" name="jurisdiction"></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Or do you mean a distance between the fields? Then use padding on the `td`s:

```css
fieldset {
  display: block;
  border: 2px groove;
  padding: 10px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
  /*padding-top: 0.35em;*/
  /*padding-bottom: 0.625em;*/
  vertical-align: top;
  border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*border-spacing: 10px 50px;*/
  padding: 20px;
}

.td.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td right">Date of Call:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="datepicker2" name="callDate"></div>
    <div class="td right">Caller code Number:</div>
    <div class="td"><input class="CodeMaker" name="callerCodeNum"></div>
    <div class="td right">Is there a warrant? If so what is the jurisdiction?</div>
    <div class="td"><input type="text" name="jurisdiction"></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Yes, that causes padding around the border of the fieldset, but it does not create padding around the "cells"

Comment: Did you see my edit / 2nd snippet?

Comment: thank you for your response. I didn't realize someone had already posted the answer on my first question.